# Uninstall Norton Safety Minder?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I am tired of using Norton Safety Minder, and want to uninstall it. Should I use Windows Add/Remove Programs, or Norton’s own uninstaller?

Answer (score 1):

From experience I'd say try Add/Remove (or Programs and Features) and then use the Norton Uninstaller as a last resort. The Norton Uninstaller does take a long time to run but does a very thorough job of cleaning up, but I wouldn't recommend running it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Norton Uninstaller is a bit overkill, its normally recommended when you have trouble removing the software.

Try a Add/Remove first, if this leads to complications further down the line then i suggest looking into Norton Uninstaller

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [Revo Uninstaller (Free)](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html). After uninstalling the program with its native uninstaller, it searchs for your disk and the entire registry for probable leftovers (files, folders, registry entries).